# How to set parameters to zip a folder in nodejs

Tags: node.js, zip, compression, 7zip

I want zip a folder which contains few files. I am using zip-folder and 7zip-min modules they are working fine. But, I would like to add some parameters to it, like compression level and directory size and so on.

If it is not possible with this module, Can anyone provide other suggestions?
Here is my code :

Example 1-

```
const zipFolder = require('zip-folder');
    zipFolder('./folder', './compressed.zip', function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('something went wrong!', err);
        } else {
            console.log('done with compressing');
        }
    });
```

Example 2-

```
  const _7z = require('7zip-min');
    let pack = _7z.pack('./folder', './compressed.7z', err => {
        console.log('I am done with compressing')
    });
```

Comment: The implementation of `zip-folder` is like [10 lines of code](https://github.com/sole/node-zip-folder/blob/master/index.js) ... uses [`archiver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) ... quick start example of archiver shows how to set compression level right in the beginning.

Comment: Similar case with [`7zip-min`](https://github.com/onikienko/7zip-min/blob/master/index.js) -- just write your own variant of `pack`, it's a oneliner...